# Matlab simulink Unable to locate a C-compiler required by Stateflow and MATLAB Function blocks. Use 'mex -setup' to select a supported C-compiler

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

I have a model in matlab simulink. I have installed matlab in D drive. When I run my model I get the following error:

```
Unable to locate a C-compiler required by Stateflow and MATLAB Function blocks.
Use 'mex -setup' to select a supported C-compiler.
```

This is not a syntax or semantics. How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: First googled [HERE](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86089-how-to-solve-this-error-as-mentioned-unable-to-locate-a-c-compiler-required-by-stateflow-and-matla)

Comment: Did you try running `mex -setup`? Is a supported compiler installed? Which matlab version are you using?

Comment: I have Matlab 2013. Also, I installed the matlab package. Up to now, I did not install other compilers.

Comment: Interesting, I installed MS Visual Studion 2012, and I used mex -setup successfully with [21] Microsoft Visual C++ 2012. However, when I run the simulink model, I still receive this error: Unable to locate a C-compiler required by Stateflow and MATLAB Function blocks. Use 'mex -setup' to select a supported C-compiler.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you need to run `mex -setup` to set up a C compiler. For a list of supported C compilers for your MATLAB version (you don't say whether it is R2013a or R2013b, and which O/S you are running on), see [Supported and Compatible Compilers – Release 2013a](http://uk.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/) and [Supported and Compatible Compilers – Release 2013b](http://uk.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/) on the MathWorks web site.

Comment: It is Matlab R2013a, and my OS is windows 8 x64. The problem is that I also do not know how to install the c compiler.

Comment: Look at the link I provided for R2013a, MathWorks lists all supported compilers and point to where you can download them from and any installation notes that are not part of the standard installation. It's really very easy: download, install, run `mex-setup`. There's not much more to it than that.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded and installed Microsoft SDK 7.1. However, when I run    mex-setup in matlab, it says: No supported SDK or compiler was found on this computer. For a list of supported compilers

Comment: Did the SDK installation finish wtihout error? Did you check you had the .NET Framework 4.0 installed or if not, installed it beforehand? Did you restart the PC afterwards?

Comment: See also http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101105-how-do-i-install-microsoft-windows-sdk-7-1

Comment: No it did not, so I installed microsoft visual studio 2013. Now I need to locate the compiler for the     mex -setup command, and I cannot.

Comment: Interesting, I installed MS Visual Studion 2012, and I used mex -setup successfully with [21] Microsoft Visual C++ 2012. However, when I run the simulink model, I still receive this error: Unable to locate a C-compiler required by Stateflow and MATLAB Function blocks.
Use 'mex -setup' to select a supported C-compiler.

Comment: Rather than try to install several compilers in succession, you should try and work out what went wrong when installing the SDK. Did you follow the steps in http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101105-how-do-i-install-microsoft-windows-sdk-7-1? There are specific instructions for Windows 8 users and if you already have some other compiler or .NET Framework installed. Check it out.

Comment: Also, if you read the list of supported compilers I mentione din my answer, you'd see that MSVS 2013 is **not** supported.